Fetch new records from DB dynamically using Flink and post to kafka/axon topic
I am new to Flink and have a use case of 2 Flink jobs, 1st to consume data from Topic1 and insert/update in DB and 2nd to fetch any new data inserted/updated in DB to Topic2 used by different services.
Method 1:
    env.fromSource(axon.source(Constants.CONSUMER_TOPIC_NAME, Constants.CONSUMER_GROUP_ID),
                    WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "foo-kafka-source").map(axonMessage ->
                    (FooModel) axonMessage.getPayload())
            .addSink(jdbc.exactlyOnceSink(new FooEntityJdbcSink()))
            .uid("foo-kafka-source");

Method 2
  DataStream<AxonMessage> stream = jdbc.source(env, new FooJdbcSource())
            .map(x -> {
                AxonMessage message = new AxonMessage(x);
                message.setTopic(Constants.PRODUCER_TOPIC_NAME);
                message.setKey(FooModel.class);
                return message;
            });

    stream.sinkTo(axon.sink()) 
            .name("foo-kafka-sink")
            .uid("foo-kafka-sink");

In FooJdbcSource, the SQL query used to fetch data is
SELECT {colm_1, colm_2, ...} FROM foo_table;

The issue is job 2 is only picking data one-time and pushing to topic. Any new records added while the job is running is not picked.  I found few solutions like JdbcDynamicTableSource or SourceFunction(deprecated) that will check the DB table at certain intervals (windowing) and fetch new data based on timestamp; but the table is not expected to frequently update and we need any changes on topic instantly in run-time without polling/monitoring the DB at intervals as it will be too many DB operations/hits. Is there any way in Flink we can dynamically monitor the DB table.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Will any other service be writing data to the DB? If not, then why can't you split your Axion source stream, and have one fork write to the DB, and the other fork write to your Axion sink?

@kkrugler If I follow that approach, then how can I make sure that data is inserted in DB and pushed to topic (as in a single transaction). Data should not be pushed to topic if not inserted in DB.

I think I saw you ask this question elsewhere in SO, which is the right thing to do. And the answer to that question was correct - run the workflow in exactly once mode, and make sure sources and (especially) sinks support and are configured for exactly once. For sinks, this means transactional support.

Depending on the type of database you are using, there are numerous Kafka-related connectors that will function as change-data capture (CDC) streams from your database to a Kafka topic which can then be listened to via your Flink job to stream through the changes/updates as they occur.
There are plenty of different supported Kafka connectors out there depending on your preferred database flavor that are independent from Flink like Debezium, which supports upports a wide array of relational and non-relational databases including:

MongoDB
MySQL
PostgreSQL
SQL Server
Oracle
Db2
Cassandra
Vitess (Incubating)
Spanner
JDBC (Incubating)
Informix (Incubating)

Flink also provides a Flink CDC project that supports additional connectors via Flink to perform the same behavior as well. Additionally, several other technologies provide their own official CDC connectors to support this behavior as well.

Thanks @RionWilliams for the help. Unfortunately, I cannot go ahead with Flink CDC. Is there any way we can do transaction management in Flink so that I can 1st sink the data stream to DB and then to Axon topic as a part of 1 transaction, so that in case my DB write fails, it will not push the data to topic as well.

Something like below:
`stream.addSink(jdbc.exactlyOnceSink(new FooMessageSink()))
.name("foo-data-db-sink")
.uid("foo-data-db-sink");
    stream.sinkTo(kafka.exactlyOnceSink(fooSchema))
            .name("foo-data-kafka-sink")
            .uid("foo-data-kafka-sink");`

